# Inline math font size and equations spacing in markdown to pdf conversion using pandoc

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc, obsidian

I'm using vim and markdown as an alternative to [obsidian](https://obsidian.md/). I'm doing the conversion from markdown to pdf using pandoc and I would like to resemble as much as possible the pdf output of obsidian since I like how it looks.

In general I could make both pdf looks almost the same, but, I got two problems, the first is that the *inline math font is too big*, the second that the spacing before and after an equation is different.

Here are two screenshots, the first one being the pandoc output, the second the obsidian output.

[image: Pandoc pdf output]

[image: Obsidian pdf output]

To style the pdf I'm using a custom latex snippet which I include with `pandoc -H style.tex ...` during the pdf compilation, with this I was able to change the spacing between the text and the sections title as well as other things like page margins, etc. But I didn't find anything related to the math nor the equation for a template

I've also tried writing the equation as `$\small \vec{E}$` but didn't work.

I think it has to be a way of changing the spacing from the latex template, I know that pandoc is using the unicode-math package to convert the latex equations but didn't find nothing related on how to change the spacing for the equations nor the font size.

EDIT: the style.tex file

```latex
% page setup
\usepackage[a4paper,
            top=2cm,
            bottom=1.75cm,
            left=1.75cm,
            right=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% inline code (backticks in md)
% taken from https://jdhao.github.io/2019/05/30/markdown2pdf_pandoc/
\linespread{1.15}
\definecolor{bgcolor}{HTML}{e0e0e0}
\let\oldtexttt\texttt

\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
    \colorbox{bgcolor}{\oldtexttt{#1}}
}

% change boldfont bold to extrabold
% \setmainfont[
%  BoldFont={Inter-ExtraBold}
% ]{Inter}

% change regular font to light font
% \setmainfont{Inter light}

\newfontfamily\titlefont{Inter}[
UprightFont     =   *-Regular,
BoldFont        =   *-ExtraBold,
]

\newfontfamily\sectionsfont{Inter}[
UprightFont     =   *-Regular,
BoldFont        =   *-SemiBold,
]

\titleformat{\section}
{\titlefont\huge\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\sectionsfont\LARGE\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\sectionsfont\Large\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\sectionsfont\large\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{2.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

EDIT2: this is the `.tex` output part showed in the screenshot
taken from:

`pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex file.md -o file.tex`

```latex
eléctrica que efectúa el campo sobre la partícula. se puede calcular entonces como:

\[\frac{w_{a \rightarrow b}}{q_{0}} = - \int_{a}^{b} \vec{e} \cdot d\vec{l} = v_{b} - v_{a} = v_{ab}\]

donde \({q_{0}}\) es una pequeña carga puntual, \(v_{a}\) y \(v_{b}\) el potencial por unidad de carga de los puntos \(a\) y \(b\) respectivamente, \(\vec{e}\) el valor del campo eléctrico
```

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Of course. I was thinking, maybe it's better if I use a custom template? would that work?

Comment: Not your sty file, the intermediate .tex file so we can see the code pandoc uses to set your equations. From your top image, I think here might be an additional empty line ...

Comment: I generated the .tex with pandoc see EDIT2, is that what you where asking?

Comment: yes, the empty lines cause additional spaces, but no idea how to tell pandoc not not insert them...